# How to get message box on top of the Popup control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

We are showing an error message from the popup control.Message box is coming but it is coming behind the popup control. How do i make popup to go back or message box to come in front. It is with MVVM.

Comment: Are you passing an owner for the MessageBox? If you pass the PopUp as an owner, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything you can do about this.

Have a look at [WPF Popup ZOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267349/wpf-popup-zorder)

The solution suggested there is to implement your own popup control instead of using the inbuilt one, and just raise its Z index so it appears where you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/903202.. Just use this popup which is created using the existing popup control.