# Connecting The ComboBox Popup Border to Main ComboBox Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm trying to match the Style of a ComboBox I'm creating to a design I have.
I'm unable to connect the Popup border to the Main Border that shows the selected ComboBox item.

I took this ComboBox Template from a site, changed some properties to match the design's style, things were coming along good until I realized I can't connect these 2 aforementioned borders. I'm not exactly sure how we could go about doing it.

I also thought about adding 2 Rows and making the ComboBox Popup Rowspawn but that didn't work either.

Creating a StackOverflow post as I ran out of ideas, any ideas are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I was able to use `VerticalOffset` to move the Popup up, where I want it to be but I can't tuck it underneath the Border I create within the ToggleButton template. `Panel.ZIndex` usage didn't help either. Still working on a way to accomplish this task.

Design:

> [image: Here's the design]

My ComboBox:

> [image: My ComboBox]

Here's the part I have an issue with (Along with other parts that I'll address myself later):

> [image: Painted the difference]

Here's my code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Border" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    CornerRadius="4"
                    Background="#FFFFFF">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Color="Black"
                                      Opacity="0.29"
                                      BlurRadius="5"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                    CornerRadius="4,0,0,4" 
                    Margin="0,0,1,0" 
                    Background="#FFFFFF" 
                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,1.7,0">
            </Border>
            
            <Canvas Width="30" 
                    Height="30"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="9,-18,0,0">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,-1,0,0" />
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <Path Data="M131.6625 270.6375A21.1875 21.1875 0 0 0 168.4125 270.6375L296.98125 51.88125C305.55 37.29375 295.25625 18.75 278.60625 18.75H21.45C4.78125 18.75 -5.49375 37.3125 3.075 51.88125L131.6625 270.6375z"
                      Stroke="{x:Null}"
                      Fill="#707070"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      Width="10"
                      Height="10"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                      UseLayoutRounding="False"
                      StrokeThickness="0"
                      StrokeStartLineCap="flat"
                      StrokeEndLineCap="flat"
                      StrokeLineJoin="miter"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707070"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                            Name="ToggleButton" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="15,3,23,3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                            Style="{x:Null}" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Margin="15,3,23,3"
                            Focusable="True" 
                            Background="#FF3F3F3F"
                            Foreground="Green"
                            Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                            Focusable="False"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide">

                            <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                  Margin="15,15,15,15">
                                <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="White"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                BorderBrush="#888888">
                                    <Border.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Color="Black"
                                      Opacity="0.29"
                                      BlurRadius="5"/>
                                    </Border.Effect>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>

                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBoxItem -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707070"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                              Padding="2"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="8,3,23,3"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: `unable to connect the Popup border to the Main Border that shows the selected ComboBox item` -> It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, which difference between the design and your combobox do you wanna address? Could you graphically highlight what's wrong?

Comment: @CorentinPane thanks for the feedback! I've updated the post to highlight the issue I have with my current design and what I'd like to change.

Comment: Okay so you want the dropdown part to look like it's behind the main box, with some nice blending?

Comment: That is correct, yes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Popup ZOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267349/wpf-popup-zorder)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem isn't that Popup is below the Main ComboBox Border, instead it's the fact that it starts below the Main ComboBox border.

As I'm tinkering with it I tried adding a negative Margin to the Popup and I could make it go up by a bit, though I'm not sure how to hide the Popup border below the Main Border.

Comment: You must use triggers to detect when the poupup is open and then: disable the bottom border of the ComboBox, disable the top border of the Popup, remove the corner radius of the adjacent border lines. You can set the radius for each of the four corners explicitly e.g., CornerRadius="4,4,0,0". Do simplify the border handling remove the border around the ToggleButton. Instead wrap the complete content of the ComboBox into a Border.

Comment: @BionicCode thank you for the suggestions but I'm not sure how I can "wrap the complete content of the ComboBox into a Border", could you give me an example?                                          

             
Also, I was able to use ```VerticalOffset``` to move the Popup up where I want it to be but I can't tuck it underneath the Border I create within the ToggleButton template.  PanelZ.Index usage didn't help either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Any new suggestions would be much appreciated, I still couldn't find a way to resolve this problem. Many thanks in advance!